# Windows 7 Emulator for MAC OS X

Tags: windows-7, osx, virtual-machine

I am looking for a Microsoft Windows 7 emulator for Mac platform.

I would not mind how restrictive it is, I just need Chrome/IE/Firefox on Windows 7 for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [Wine on Mac](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX). It should work on Intel Macs - older PowerPC Macs won't work. It can run Firefox and Chrome/Chromium, as well as Internet Explorer up to version 8. 32bit applications work best, only some 64bit may run - it will works Windows XP by default, you can change to Windows 7 in settings.

Possibly the only builds available are from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/darwine/), instructions to install via [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/) are available [here](http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/#part-2).

As someone who does not use Windows much, I have found that for testing in newer versions of Internet Explorer (9+) you will need to run a Windows VM as suggested in @SteveBarnes, if you do not have a actual Windows machine available. Newer versions can to some extent simulate older versions I think as well.

Comment: thanks! I did think to wine but couldn't remember if it was Linux exclusive. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.modern.ie/ offer free download of various virtual machines XP through 10 with IE 6-11 & Edge for testing on Windows, OS-X & Linux & for various VM bases.  They are time limited but can be reinstalled.

### UPDATE Oct 2020

The site has now moved to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ but currently (October 2020) offers VMs for Win7/8/10 with specific browsers to test use.
[image: Select VM]

Comment: https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/ to save a few clicks :)

Comment: @Wilf and Steve: Any updated URL for this?  Link not working at this time.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VirtualBox / virtual machine. Actually you can intsall any OS (as far as I know) using virtual machine.

I haven't used Mac much but guess you just need VirtualBox installed on your mac and Windows image file.